# Solving this equation question $\frac{5-q}{6-4} = 2 (\frac{q}{4})$ for $q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not understand why the following equation:

$\frac{5-q}{6-4} = 2 (\frac{q}{4})$

Becomes the following in the next step to solve it for $q$:

$\frac{5-q}{6-4} \times 2 = 2 (\frac{q}{4}) \times 2$

Besides this stage, I solved the equation: $q = 2.5$.

This is a high school math question, so a high school level answer would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, there's nothing stopping you from multiplying both sides by $2$.  Since $6-4=2$ that has the desirable effect of clearing the denominator on the left.

Comment: @lulu I'm stupid and I didn't notice this. Thank you.

Comment: If $a = b$ then $\text{anything you do to }a = \text{doing the same thing to }b$.  so if $a=b$ then $a\times 2 = b\times 2$.   (But you can't go the other way: If $\text{something you do to }a = \text{doing the same thing to }b$ that doesn't mean $a=b$.  Example  $13=13$ and $13=\color{blue}{12+(}5\color{blue}{-6)^2}$ and $13=\color{blue}{12+(}7\color{blue}{-6)^2}$ but $5\ne 7$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $6-4$ on the left makes the denominator $2$ so they are multiplying both sides of the equation by $2$ to clear that denominator.  The next step is probabaly to
$$5-q=q$$ as both denominators are cleared.